# How can I show cone style in a highcharts column chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to show cone charts just like below images in a column charts.
But I can't find any style in [HighCharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts).
Anyone please teach me How to change style to cone.
thank you.

[cone charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Krnx.png)

Comment: I do not think it is possible in highcharts, try anychart

Comment: You can achieve that result with a polygon series. http://jsfiddle.net/rjm1yq8d/

Comment: thank you @morganfree I solve it